# How can I do import on unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

Im having few problems on unittest.

When I run the test by vscode test, all test run fine.

But when I run the test by CLI, the error ModuleNotFoundError raises.

I need to push de projet on a pipeline, who runs the CLI version of unittes

My imports:

```
from scr.external import db
from src.exerternal import info_email
...
```

the error:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raul_gomes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\raul_gomes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\raul_gomes\Documents\repos\autopilotdaocsgorderservices\src\test\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.external import db
  File "C:\Users\raul_gomes\Documents\repos\autopilotdaocsgorderservices\src\external\db\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import configuration
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configuration'
```

Comment: What is the folder structure like and how are you calling the unit test from cli?

Comment: src/
src/test/...
src/model/...
src/util/...
src/app.py
src/configuration.py

Comment: Im calling unit test with the command: python -m unittest discover src/test